# WMIC command to find update

Tags: update, wmi

Is there a way to find if multiple MS updates are installed using WMIC command:

wmic qfe | find  ?

Thanks

Comment: uh yes using pretty much the command you already provided. What are you specifically trying to do?

Comment: yes but i want to query about multiple update at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to what you have in your question, you can do this:

```
wmic qfe | findstr /G:C:\Temp\KBs.txt
```

where `C:\Temp\KBs.txt` is the full path to a text file of the updates you are looking for.  You can list the KB #s on separate lines in the file to search for multiple updates.

Comment: Thanks August, but its not showing anything

Comment: what does it show when you just do a 'wmic qfe | findstr kb######'?  That should limit the output to just the 1 update.  Putting each kb###### on a separate line in the txt file and running the command above should limit it to just the updates you are looking for.

Comment: still doesnt show anything, although when i tried findstr kb only it showed all the updates installed

Comment: Thanks August its working, do you know how to report the not found also

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. Updates that aren't installed won't show up in the results.

Comment: yes i know, is there a way to show the report as installed and not installed

Comment: no you'd get that functionality from a WSUS or SCCM server. It would be able to show you the updates that have been installed and what the computers need to install. The wmic command only queries for what is on the computer already. See http://blogs.technet.com/b/jonjor/archive/2009/04/21/are-all-of-my-servers-really-up-to-date.aspx for some more wmic qfe commands.